# Cannot resize an SVG image in React Native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg, expo

I have the following `React Native` project:

https://snack.expo.io/BkBU8fAlV

where I have the following code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

import HomerSvg from './assets/HomerSvg';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
        </Text>
        <View style={{ width: 80, height: 80 }}>
          <HomerSvg />
        </View>
        <Card>
          <AssetExample />
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

I display the `SVG` image through the component: `HomerSvg` which uses the `react-native-svg` package.

What I need is to resize somehow the `SVG` image. On the code above I did a try with no success.

I tried by giving the container view some width and height with no success.

Do you have any idea on how can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Resize works with width and height which is you already applied, can you explain more?

Comment: can you show your resolved code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap all the `<Path />` elements inside a `<G />` and scale the `<G />` component by calculating the scale factor using `Dimensions` i.e width and height of the device.

```
<G transform="scale(scaleFactor) translate(offsetX,offsetY)>
<Path/>
<Path/>
.
.
.
<G/>
```

where scaleFactor, offsetX and offsetY can be calculated via `const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window")`

Comment: Hi, can you please show a better example, I am struggling with this

Comment: Where does G come from?

Answer (score 11):

This is actually very easy to solve without React Native but SVG itself.

Just set the `preserveAspectRatio` tag to `none`.

Example:

```
<Svg
  width={this.props.width}
  height={this.heights.h1}
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  viewBox="0 0 750 352"
  preserveAspectRatio="none">
...
</Svg>
```

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question but maybe we're forgetting the fundamentals here, remember that some imported SVGs can be provided a **width** and **height**.

```
import HomeSvg from './assets/HomeSvg';

<HomeSvg height={20} width={20}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that SVG optimizations removed `viewBox`.
Try adding `viewBox="0 0 width height"` prop to the `Svg` (`width` and `height` being the original dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the SVG's dimensions are based on the containers dimensions, they will not change. Images with set dimensions ignore their parent's dimensions, and you set the dimensions in HomerSvg.js

Hope this helps!